# Wait and notify for sending bunch of messages

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, concurrency

Would be super grateful if someone can explain me how wait/notify/notifyAll works and if is there better solution for the problem I am facing. Basically, we have to send a bunch of SMS messages. For sending messages an object called SMPPSession is used but in this example I'll just use superficial code. SMPPSession is supposed to send messages to SMSC server and to reestablish session in situations when connection breaks.  I would like to use multiple threads for sending multiple messages, and to have a separate single thread, some sort of "guardian"/ "watcher"/"notifier".  The role of that separate thread is to stop all other threads from executing their code, while it works on reestablishing session. Naturally, SMPPSession is shared among all these threads. Once that guardian finishes reconnecting, all other thread needs to continue with using the session and proceed with sending.

Now, I have some code and getting exception. Any help?

In reality we do send real SMS messages using jsmpp library and inside it there is SMPPSession object.

```
    public class SMPPSession {
 
    private boolean bind;
    private static final Random idGenerator = new Random();
 
    public int sendMessage(String msg){
       try{
           Thread.sleep(1000L);
           System.out.println("Sending message: " + msg);
           return Math.abs(idGenerator.nextInt());
       } catch (InterruptedException e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
        return -1;
    }
 
    public void reBind(){
        try{
            System.out.println("Rebinding...");
            Thread.sleep(1000L);
            this.bind = true;
            System.out.println("Session established!");
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
 
    public boolean isBind(){
        return this.bind;
    }
}
 
public class Sender extends Thread{
 
    private SMPPSession smppSession;
 
    public Sender(String name, SMPPSession smppSession){
        this.setName(name);
        this.smppSession = smppSession;
    }
 
    @Override
    public void run(){
 
        while (!Client.messages.isEmpty()){
 
            synchronized (Client.messages){
 
                    if (smppSession.isBind()){
                        final String msg = Client.messages.remove(0);
                        final int msgId = smppSession.sendMessage(msg);
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " sent msg and received msgId: " + msgId);
                        Client.messages.notifyAll();
                } else {
                    try {
                        Client.messages.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
            }
 
        }
 
    }
}
 
public class SessionProducer extends Thread{
 
    private SMPPSession smppSession;
 
    public SessionProducer(String name, SMPPSession smppSession){
        this.setName(name);
        this.smppSession = smppSession;
    }
 
    @Override
    public void run(){
 
        while (!Client.messages.isEmpty()){
 
            synchronized (Client.messages){
                if (!smppSession.isBind()){
                    smppSession.reBind();
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " managed to reestablish SMPP session.");
                    Client.messages.notifyAll();
                } else{
                    try {
                        Client.messages.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
            }
 
        }
 
    }
}
 
public class Client {
 
    public static final List<String> messages = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
 
        //populate messages from db
        messages.add("msg1"); messages.add("msg2"); messages.add("msg3");  messages.add("msg4"); messages.add("msg5"); messages.add("msg6");
 
        SMPPSession smppSession = new SMPPSession();
        SessionProducer sessionProducer = new SessionProducer("SessionProducer1", smppSession);
        Sender sender1 = new Sender("Sender1", smppSession);
        Sender sender2 = new Sender("Sender2", smppSession);
        Sender sender3 = new Sender("Sender3", smppSession);
        Sender sender4 = new Sender("Sender4", smppSession);
 
        sessionProducer.start();
        sender1.start();
        sender2.start();
        sender3.start();
        sender4.start();
 
    }
}
 
Naturally, I get exception and have no idea why. Somehow threads are not in sync.
 
 
Rebinding...
Session established!
SessionProducer1 managed to reestablish SMPP session.
Sending message: msg1
Sender4 sent msg and received msgId: 432995458
Sending message: msg2
Sender4 sent msg and received msgId: 113629699
Sending message: msg3
Sender4 sent msg and received msgId: 611735717
Sending message: msg4
Sender4 sent msg and received msgId: 1234995659
Sending message: msg5
Sender4 sent msg and received msgId: 922228968
Sending message: msg6
Sender4 sent msg and received msgId: 2097204472
Exception in thread "Sender2" Exception in thread "Sender1" Exception in thread "Sender3" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList.elementAt(CopyOnWriteArrayList.java:385)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList.remove(CopyOnWriteArrayList.java:478)
    at demo.Sender.run(Sender.java:20)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList.elementAt(CopyOnWriteArrayList.java:385)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList.remove(CopyOnWriteArrayList.java:478)
    at demo.Sender.run(Sender.java:20)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList.elementAt(CopyOnWriteArrayList.java:385)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList.remove(CopyOnWriteArrayList.java:478)
    at demo.Sender.run(Sender.java:20)
```

Comment: Re, "Would be super grateful if someone can explain me how wait/notify/notifyAll works " https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html

Comment: Your four `Sender` threads and your `SessionProducer` thread can never work at the same time. Whenever any one of them is working, the others all are `wait()`ing. What's the point of making them separate threads? Why not just do all of the work in one thread?

Answer (score 0):

Your loops call `Client.messages.isEmpty()` with no synchronization. I haven't spent the time to *really* understand what your code does—can't see all of it anyway—but I can *guess* what's happening.

Maybe the list contains one message.

- Four threads all see it as not empty.
- Four threads all try enter the `synchronized(Client.messages)` block.
- One-by-one, they get in to the block, see that `smppSession.isBind()` is true, and try to remove a message from the list.
- The first thread to remove a message succeeds, and then each of the other four throws an exception because it tried to remove from an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

Recommend a SMS development library [sms-client](https://github.com/Lihuanghe/sms-client) from China to support Smpp.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.chinamobile.cmos</groupId>
  <artifactId>sms-client</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.7</version>
</dependency>
```

---

```
public void testsmpp() throws Exception {
    SmsClientBuilder builder = new SmsClientBuilder();
    SmsClient smsClient = builder.uri("smpp://127.0.0.1:18890?username=test01&password=1qaz2wsx&version=52&window=32&maxchannel=1")
    .receiver(new MessageReceiver() {
        public void receive(BaseMessage message) {
            logger.info("receive : {}",message.toString());
        }
    }).build();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        
        SubmitSm pdu = new SubmitSm();
        pdu.setRegisteredDelivery((byte)1);
        pdu.setSourceAddress(new Address((byte)0,(byte)0,"10086"));
        pdu.setDestAddress(new Address((byte)0,(byte)0,"13800138000"));
        pdu.setSmsMsg(new SmsTextMessage("SmsTextMessage " + i,SmsDcs.getGeneralDataCodingDcs(SmsAlphabet.GSM,SmsMsgClass.CLASS_UNKNOWN)));
        try {
            smsClient.send(pdu, 1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info("send ", e);
        }
    }
    Thread.sleep(5000000);
}
```